# How can I test an AWS API Gateway API Route without using the AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-api-gateway-v2

I'm following the [AWS Tutorial "Using Lambda with API Gateway"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway-tutorial.html#services-apigateway-tutorial-invoke-cli). I have set up my Lambda function and API gateway, and now want to test the API connection to the lambda function (I tried in CURL and got a 500, I want to dig deeper).

According to the tutorial, I can test using some kind of webapp feature:

> You're now ready to test the integration of your API Gateway API method with your Lambda function and your DynamoDB table. Using the API Gateway console, you send requests directly to your POST method using the console's test function.

> 1. In the API Gateway console, choose your API...

I do so:

[image: screenshot of my API list]

> 2. In the Resources tree... choose your POST method.

There is no resources tree, nor does ctrl+f show anything like that:

[image: screenshot of the navigation tree]

However the tutorial mentions the `/dynamodbmanager` route so I click "routes." There I can see my POST method, so I click it.

> 3 In the Method Execution pane, in the Client box, choose Test.

There is no Method Execution pane, there is no Client box, there is no Test button:

[image: screenshot of the routes screen]

The AWS help article "[Use the API Gateway console to test a REST API method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-test-method.html)" has essentially identical instructions.

Perhaps the docs are out of date? **How can I test APIs in API Gateway within the AWS website?**

Answer (score 0):

The API type, on creation, was incorrect. I had selected maybe HTTP type, when I should have selected REST type:

[image: screenshot of API create page]

When I made a new API of the REST type, I can see the resources tree:

[image: screenshot of navigation tree]